# VB.NET Appending table to a database from DataTable object

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, oledb, dao

I am trying to convert some old VB6 code into VB.NET. The old code used DAO and now I am trying to replicate it in ADO.NET/OleDB. I have made some advances (I think...) but now I can't figure out how to add the DataTable object into the database.

Here is the old VB6 code, td is a TableDef object from DAO:

```
If fso.FileExists(loc) Then
    Set td = m_db.CreateTableDef("Ratings")
    td.Connect = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & loc
    td.SourceTableName = "Sheet1$"
    m_db.TableDefs.Append td
    bFileNotExists = False
Else
    bFileNotExists = True
End If
```

From what I understand this is reading Sheet1 from the Excel file 'loc' and then appending it to m_db, a DAO database object. This is what I have so far, and please correct me if you see any mistakes as I'm just getting started with this sort of thing -

```
If fso.FileExists(loc) Then
        oleCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & loc & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;")
        oleCon.Open()
        oleAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oleCon)
        oleAdapter.Fill(dt)

        bFileNotExists = False
    Else
        bFileNotExists = True
    End If
```

So instead of the TableDef, I am taking the data from the same sheet and putting it in a DataTable object (dt). I hope this is correct so far. Now my question is how to replicate the `m_db.TableDefs.Append td` line from above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that you have to pre-load the 'dt' with the configuration in the Excel-file, in order for the TableAdapter to work out. This is as far as I know. There's many paths you can take, including first creating columns and then loading row-by-row, or loading the Excel-sheet in as a DataTable itself and add this to a DataSet.

Suggestions:

- Start using CamelCase programming notation. This really helps out and prevents errors.
- Read up on ADO.NET, for example by following some tutorials.
- Drop OleDb handling, ADO.NET suffices.
- Realize the differences between VB.Net and VB6, and prepare to learn some more object-oriented programming